# What is the correct way to share a locking reference to a resource in AVR (no_std) Rust?

Tags: rust

I have two device drivers that need to use the SPI bus.

Fortunately the one that wants to "own" it, uses a trait, and I can interpose my own implementation.

If this were regular Rust an `Arc<Mutex<SPI>>` would be sufficient, but I am encountering challenges.

```
extern crate alloc;

use alloc::sync::Arc;
use avr_hal_generic::avr_device::interrupt::{CriticalSection, Mutex};

...

let spi = Arc::new(Mutex::new(spi));
let device_interface = SpiWorkaround::new(spi.clone(), cs, dc);
```

When I try to compile this in a project based off the https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal-template I get

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `alloc`
 --> src/main.rs:5:1
  |
5 | extern crate alloc;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

If I add `alloc="*"` to the `Cargo.toml` I get

```
error: no matching package named `alloc` found
location searched: registry `crates-io`
```

I was able to get past these using `cargo build --release -Z build-std=core,alloc` (is there a way to put that in the `Cargo.toml`?) and got this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `alloc::sync`
 --> src/main.rs:7:12
  |
7 | use alloc::sync::Arc;
  |            ^^^^ could not find `sync` in `alloc`
```

What is the proper technique for letting two data structures take turns using an object in the no_std AVR environment?

Comment: What board do you use?

Comment: I have an Arduino Uno and an Arduino Mega.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `Arc` for that. [`Arc` uses atomic `usize` for its reference counter](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/349bda2051e94b7aefb33d6541f48f561bf06dbc/library/alloc/src/sync.rs#L317), and therefore [only supports target that have `usize`-sized atomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/349bda2051e94b7aefb33d6541f48f561bf06dbc/library/alloc/src/lib.rs#L226-L227). Unfortunately the size of `usize` for your platform is 16 bits, but it only supports up to 8 bits atomics.

You can copy the source code of `Arc` from std and adapt it to use `AtomicU8` instead of `AtomicUsize` (there may already be a crate for that, I didn't found one though). Note this will only support up to 255 active owners.

As for the other question, you can put change `.cargo/config.toml` `[build-std]` key as follows to avoid the need to pass `-Zbuild-std` every time:

```rust
[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "alloc"]
```

Comment: copying Arc is proving to be challenging.  It uses a number of pub(crate) functions, and methods like compare_exchange and fetch_add are missing from the AtomicU8 implementation on AVR.  I might have to investigate the atomic-polyfill crate to see if it solves these problems.